# How can I avoid float (in)accuracy affecting rounding

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

I work for the NHS producing clinical outcomes data and have a long-standing problem with rounding in Python 3. Previously on here I've been provided an excellent code to produce the rounding I require (i.e. not Banker's Rounding) but I have since realised that an additional problem I have is the accuracy of the float fields themselves. The specific example I've encountered is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import math
raw_data = {'AreaCode' : ['101', '101', '101'],
            'Disaggregation' : ['1864', '65Over', 'Total'],
            'Numerator' : [19.0, 82.0, 101.0],
            'Denominator' : [24.0, 160.0, 184.0]}

Data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['AreaCode', 'Disaggregation', 'Numerator', 'Denominator'])

Data['Outcome'] = (Data['Numerator'] / (Data['Denominator'])*100)

Data
```

As this shows, the Outcome for the 65+ is 52.250000. this keeps rounding to 52.2, despite me using the ROUND_UP instructing against this.

When I multiply this 52.2500 Outcome by 1000000000 it displays as 512499999, hence why it rounds to 52.2.

How can I guard against this?

I've coded a snippet above to demo, but in my real-world exercise I am importing the full raw data with numerators and denominators from a CSV, and then calculating the Outcomes in Python. Do I need to add some code to my pd.read_csv at the start to make sure num/denom don't import as floats? Or make sure my Outcome calculation isn't a float? Or both?

Any help or pointers would be brilliant thanks

James

Comment: Do you have to use pandas? Because you problem is fundamentally fixed-size, binary floating point numbers. You should consider using `fractions.Fraction` objects, which can represent rational numbers exactly, or use `decmal.Decimal` objects, which are arbitrary-sized and the representation is decimal instead of binary.

Comment: Hi Juanpa, no not at all - would be happy to use whatever works. I did try installing the Decimal package but didn't have much joy with it. Would I need to perform some sort of conversion on the fields to decimal first and then produce the Outcome field?

Comment: you don't need to install any of those, they are part of the standard library. You should just be able to `import decimal` or `import fractions`

Comment: Yes, instead of using `float` objects, you would need to use either `decimal.Decimal` objects or `fractions.Fraction` objects. Both should probably be from `str` objects, when you have a `float` object, the precision is already lost

Comment: Ok thanks - so at point of entry, importing my CSV, the numerator and denominator columns would need to be brought in as str objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer: Based on comments of @juanpa.arrivallaga you could also solve your problem this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import math
raw_data = {'AreaCode' : ['101', '101', '101'],
            'Disaggregation' : ['1864', '65Over', 'Total'],
            'Numerator' : [19.0, 82.0, 101.0],
            'Denominator' : [24.0, 160.0, 184.0]}

Data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['AreaCode', 'Disaggregation', 'Numerator', 'Denominator'])

Data['Outcome'] = (Data['Numerator'] / (Data['Denominator'])*100)

from decimal import *
def division_using_decimals(numerator,denominator):
    return Decimal(numerator)/Decimal(denominator)

#loop using list comprehension
Data['Outcome_alternative'] = [100*division_using_decimals(Data['Numerator'][x],Data['Denominator'][x]) for x in range(len(Data))]
```

Please note that if you pass the Decimal class to float for examlpe for the first number
float(Data['Outcome_alternative'][0]) you'll get the rounded number. If you use str(Data['Outcome_alternative'][0]) you actually get your number but as an string.